# How do I get the default Android home button in my toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

On the top left hand side of my toolbar I want a default Android back arrow (in white) that takes you to the previous page. For some reason it doesn't show. Here is what I'm doing

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3f9845")));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Am I missing a line or something? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have extends **ActionBarActivity**.
basically given code are used to show back arrow and it running perfectly into my phone

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and below code is used to perform the action on through back button

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```